# How to properly use latest Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, upgrade, xorg

As a newer Ubuntu user switching from Windows a few months ago (and couldn't be happier), I have to seek help with the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

I've only been able to get the nvidia-331-updates drivers (or earlier) to work correctly with my system, but the 340 or 346 (most current I believe?) from xorg-edgers ppa leave me with either a black screen or a total freeze on the splash screen at bootup.

I am on a laptop with an Intel i7/Nvidia Geforce GTX 860M setup, so I have a feeling Optimus technology is party to blame for my problems, although I currently have everything running correctly with Bumblebee ONLY while the 331-updates or older drivers are installed.

I realize that there are many forum posts that address this or similar issues, and believe me I have read ta lot of them, but either they haven't solved my problem or my technical expertise in the Linux environment is still lacking.

From a few things I read, this may be a problem caused by a kernel update and how it relates to the drivers from this repository? Should I just deal with it and wait for updates? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? Somehow I have 3 computers with 14.04 and each one has a different setup in terms of video. One has NVidia 340, but the other two are stuck on NVidia 304, but the list of installed modules is different on each machine... I'm wondering whether I need to do something to get the other two at version 340.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great explanation here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

1. Go to http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
2. Enter your card information to determine the most recent driver version (e.g. 361.42)
3. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-{the major version of your card driver}` e.g. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`.
4. Restart your system.
5. open NVIDIA X Server Settings to verify.

Comment: nvidia-settings is a separate package that can be installed separately, regardless of the Nvidia driver version.